# Deny all collection actions?

Tags: meteor

I've removed the `autopublish` package, and I'm perfectly ok with only using `Meteor.methods` as the sole interface to call procedures on the server. However, I just discovered the client can still delete things by simply running `MyModel.remove({ _id: 'someid' })` in the console.

What's the best way to deny all such actions on all collections in Meteor?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest way is to remove the `insecure` package. If you have no `allow` rules then by default all inserts from the client will be denied:

```
meteor remove insecure
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `insecure` package. If you don't have any [allow](https://docs.meteor.com/#/full/allow) or [deny](https://docs.meteor.com/#/full/deny) rules, the default action will be to deny all client-side database mutations.